# Azure Object Anchors - What 3D model formats are supported by Azure Object Anchors?

Tags: azure-object-anchors

What 3D model formats are supported by Azure Object Anchors? Does someone know all supported formats?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, ***FBX, GLTF/GLB, OBJ, PLY*** 3D model formats are supported by Azure Object Anchors.